# IE9 print preview mistakenly indents first <li>'s number

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

IE9 is mistakenly indenting an `<li>`s number when print previewing if the `<ol>` is the first item to be printed on that page.  The number is indented over to its corresponding text - and overlapping it.  This only occurs at the top of printed pages, where the previous printed page has the parent `ol` tag, and it's continued to print on the next page. The rest of the  `<li>`s are indented normally.  It's fine in Chrome, but what am I missing in IE? Is it a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround, not a solution: I ended up applying this class to the element previous to this one:

```
.forcePageBreak {page-break-before:always;}
```

This class moves that previous element, and the problematic `<li>` I've been trying to fix, to the next printed page.  I then saw that in IE9, the problematic `<li>` had no indenting issue.